# Web Scraping tables in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Complete noob trying to scrape the table on this page, the furthest I've got is loading the rvest package. My problems are:

1. I couldn't find the right element; the element I tried via inspector is "table.w782.comm.lsjz" but it returns a list of length 0, and doing %>% .[[1]] after html_table() ie `fund_page %>% html_nodes("table.w782.comm.lsjz") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]` doesn't work either

(Error in .[[1]] : subscript out of bounds)

```
fund_link <- "https://fundf10.eastmoney.com/jjjz_510300.html"
fund_page <- read_html(fund_link)
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes("table.w782.comm.lsjz") %>% html_table()
```

2. The table has multiple pages (113), but clicking onto page 2 doesn't reload the html and so I have no idea how to scrape all 113 pages of data onto one page...

Really appreciate any pointers as to what I could do...

Comment: https://fundf10.eastmoney.com/F10DataApi.aspx?type=lsjz&code=510300&page=1&sdate=2019-01-01&edate=2021-02-13&per=40

Found a somewhat easier version of the website but still... none of the code works yet

Comment: The reason a table is not found is because technically one doesn't exist in the code. Instead there is a script in the code that creates a table. I know it is "basically the same thing", but it really isn't. You would first have to clean up the code so that there is just a table there and no {{if}} statements or script information.

Comment: Thought it was my problem, since power query worked and extracted a table out of it so it must have been there!

Answer (score 0):

In your original question the problem is that the table is showing up as a script instead of a valid xml/html table. Using the API link you got was definately the way to go.

```
library(rvest)

# You gave an API link and this is the best option for getting the data.
fund_link <- "https://fundf10.eastmoney.com/F10DataApi.aspx?type=lsjz&code=510300&page=1&sdate=2019-01-01&edate=2021-02-13&per=40"
fund_page <- read_html(fund_link)

# Any of these seem to work
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes(css = "table") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes(css = "table.w782") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes(css = "table.comm") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes(css = "table.lsjz") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes(css = "table.w782.comm.lsjz") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]


# Original Question:
fund_link <- "https://fundf10.eastmoney.com/jjjz_510300.html"
fund_page <- read_html(fund_link)

# The following doesn't work because the table you want is actually a script, not a table.
# <script id="lsjzTable" type="text/html">
#   {{if Data && Data.LSJZList}}
# <table class="w782 comm lsjz">
#   <thead>
#   <tr>
#   <th class="first"><U+51C0><U+503C><U+65E5><U+671F></th>
#   {{if ((Data.FundType!="004" && Data.FundType!="005") || "510300"=="511880")}}
# <th><U+5355><U+4F4D><U+51C0><U+503C></th>
#   <th><U+7D2F><U+8BA1><U+51C0><U+503C></th>
#   {{if Data.FundType=="100"}}
# <th><U+5468><U+589E><U+957F><U+7387></th>
#   {{else}}
# <th><U+65E5><U+589E><U+957F><U+7387><img id="jjjzTip" style="position: relative; top: 3px; left: 3px;" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" title="<U+65E5><U+589E><U+957F><U+7387><U+4E3A><U+7A7A><U+539F><U+56E0><U+5982><U+4E0B>:<br>1<U+3001><U+975E><U+4EA4><U+6613><U+65E5><U+51C0><U+503C><U+4E0D><U+53C2><U+4E0E><U+65E5><U+589E><U+957F><U+7387><U+8BA1><U+7B97>(<U+7070><U+8272><U+6570><U+636E><U+884C>)<U+3002><br>2<U+3001><U+4E0A><U+4E00><U+4EA4><U+6613><U+65E5><U+51C0><U+503C><U+672A><U+62AB><U+9732>,<U+65E5><U+589E><U+957F><U+7387><U+65E0><U+6CD5><U+8BA1><U+7B97><U+3002>" src="//j5.dfcfw.com/image/201307/20130708102440.gif"></th>
#   {{/if}}
fund_table <- fund_page %>% html_nodes(css = "table") %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]

# The following is a partial solution but isn't fully working.
fund_table <- fund_page %>% 
  html_nodes("script#lsjzTable") %>%
  as.character(.) %>%
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\{\\{.+?\\}\\}") %>%
  stringr::str_remove_all("\\<\\/?script.*?\\>") %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: >Using the API link you got was definately the way to go. 

Thank you so much for this man, really reassuring to hear that instead of having to keep trying with the old link.